# HTC One with java.net.Socket stuck in DataInputStream.read when on HSDPA. Work fine on 3G and Wifi

Tags: sockets

It's on Android. I have a chat tool that sends/receives packets. On the client side I parse the packets and display the message to users. A traditional chatting tool.

The problem is the tool works quite well on other devices on wifi, Edge and 3G, except the HTC One. On HSDPA (3G) we notice that the client cannot receive the packets as usual. It's stuck there until we reset the socket.

I debug and found that the DataInputStream.read() method (in the while loop to listen to the incoming data) is stuck there. I attached Android source to go deeper but not until the java.libcore package of Oracle.

I guess the issue is because of the Sleep mode of the HTC One. But on foreground, the app cannot receive the message too, until we open a new socket (with a long timeout, about 4 minutes, which is too long for a chatting tool).

As I researched, I try to install the SmartSync Disabler for HTC and the situation seems to be better. When I decompile the tool, it only sets 2 parameters: sleep_mode_mode to off and data_on_wifi to off, which means on the sleep mode, SmartSync does not disconnect wifi.

My question is has anyone encountered this situation before on HTC One in particular? What could be the reason?

Many thanks!

Comment: have you tried using NIO?  You're probably running into a weird problem with the blocking reads and the sleep stuff.  NIO would likely handle that for you with asynchronous IO.

Answer (score 0):

We have just got the same problem.

Try to  play with this methods

```
void    setReceiveBufferSize(int size)
void    setSendBufferSize(int size)
```

I.e. make it much smaller.